# Как сбросить значения по умолчанию для составных свойств в PropertyGrid?

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

У меня есть класс со свойствами в качестве объектов каких-то еще классов.
Например:

```
    public Class Humans
    {
      public Person Human {get; set;}
      [DefaulValue("New York")]
      public string Sity {get; set;}
    }

    public struct Person
    {
      [DefaulValue("Name")]
      public string Name {get; set;}

      [DefaulValue("Surname ")]
      public string Surname {get; set;}
    }
```

Если я хочу сбросить значение класса Humans, то я пишу так:

```
    PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Humans);
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor pr in props)
    {
        if (pr.Attributes.OfType<DefaultValueAttribute>().Any())
        {
            pr.ResetValue(obj);
        }
    }
```

В случае со свойством Sity все происходит отлично, а для свойства Human ничего не происходит. Так вот, как сбрасывать на умолчания значения таких свойств?

Comment: Чем `DefaultValue(null)` не подходит? Или у вас `Human` по умолчанию не `null`?

Comment: @Raider, по умолчанию в свойствах Human я указываю значения. При сбросе значений на умолчания в классе Humans, я хочу чтобы умолчания наступили и в Human.

Comment: Вы не пробовали декорировать свойство Humans.Human атрибутом [DefaultValue](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_ComponentModel_DefaultValueAttribute__ctor_System_Type_System_String_)? Вполне возможно, что понадобится создать свой TypeConverter  для преобразования в/из строки.